# wso2 esb rewriterule replace & with %26 in query

Tags: url-rewriting, wso2, ampersand, wso2-esb

This is actual query:

```
?param1=xxx&param2=yyy&zzz
```

param2 takes yyy&zzz value

Now I need to replace `yyy&zzz` with `yyy%26zzz`. But not replace the first ampersand with %26 in the query. How do I achieve this in wso2 esb using urlrewrite?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this change to url using [Script mediator](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB403/Script+Mediator) in WSO2 ESB. For example the following script mediator configuration would get the url of 'To' property of the soap header and do the replacement you want.

```
<script language="js">var url = mc.getTo().toString();
var newURL = url.replace("yyy&amp;zzz","yyy%26zzz");
mc.setTo(newURL);</script>
```

Likewise you can get any url in the message context and do transformations to that.

Answer (score 0):

You just replace the url using xpath unction fn:replace(index,index)